# Unable to create an object of type 'MyDBContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, onion-architecture

I am working on a project on asp.net core 6 platforms. I get an error when adding a migration.
I didn't have this problem in the previous version (asp.net core 5) and MVC architecture, but I decided to use onion architecture to do this project.
In asp.net core 6 there is no startup.cs file and all its settings are moved to the program.cs file, so I can't diagnose the problem properly.
I also tried all the suggested solutions on the internet
I even created a constructor with no parameters in the DB context file but it gave the error again

** In addition, I plan to use the Connection String in the program.cs file and not use it in the Configuration method in DBContext **

Thanks

Error after run add-migration :

> Unable to create an object of type 'AhanoDBContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

MyDBContext :

```
public class AhanoDBContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, string, UserClaim, UserRole, IdentityUserLogin<string>, RoleClaim, IdentityUserToken<string>>
{
    public AhanoDBContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        //with this function init all mapping which available in this function(for Identity)
        builder.AddCustomIdentityMappings();
        //with this function init all mapping which available in this function(for Application->Ahano)
        builder.AddCustomAhanoMappings();
        //Take Now DateTime from Server and get value automatically
        builder.Entity<Product>().Property(b => b.PublishDateTime).HasDefaultValueSql("CONVERT(datetime,GetDate())");
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories { set; get; }
    public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { set; get; }
    public virtual DbSet<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ProductsImage> ProductsImages { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Newsletter> Newsletters { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ProductTag> ProductTags { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

}
```

Program.cs :

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var app = builder.Build();


// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AhanoDBContext>(options =>
{
//The name of the connection string is taken from appsetting.json under ConnectionStrings
options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseDBConnString"));
});


// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
 app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
 // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, 
 see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
 app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Comment: Hello. I guess that for migrations, you must have a parameterless constructor (did not saw any...).

Comment: Hello Ricardo, I even used the parameterless constructor, but it gave another error. In general, the problem was not solved

Comment: "In asp.net core 6 there is no startup.cs file and all its settings are moved to the program.cs file" just because there are new templates in 6, doesn't mean you have to use them.

Comment: @Pezhvak what error came up when you used a parameterless constructor?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Does that mean I manually create the startup.cs file and do the settings as before?

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext

Comment: This tutorial; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio appears to have completed examples showing both styles https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/data/ef-rp/intro/samples/cu-completed-stages/part4/ContosoUniversity & https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/data/ef-rp/intro/samples/cu60

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Thank you for introducing the documents. But I didn't see any difference between my code and the documentation you introduced. I even added the AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter service, but the problem was not solved.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, after trying all the solutions, I could solve the problem for now, but I'm not sure if it's the right way.
After adding a constructor without parameters, the **AddDBContext** service was not recognized in the **program.cs** file and I had to override the **OnConfiguring** method in MyDBContext and write the connection string.
But I think that because I use **onion architecture**, this is incorrect in terms of **security** or other reasons, because of the program.cs file is in one layer and my **context** is in another layer.
I will be glad if you have a solution to solve the problem of **AddDBContext** not being recognized and tell me if what I did will cause problems for my project in the future.

OnConfiguring method in **MyDBContext** :

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder 
 optionsBuilder)
{
  optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=(local);Initial 
  Catalog=AhanoDB;Integrated Security=true");
}
```

The method that is not recognized in file **Program.cs** and I keep facing the error of overriding the service :

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AhanoDBContext>(options => 
options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString
("DatabaseDBConnString")));
```

Good luck to your dear ones

Answer (score 3):

Try to add

```
    public AhanoDBContext()
    {
    }
```

in your `MyDBContext` file. Like below, it works for me.

```
public class AhanoDBContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, string, UserClaim, UserRole, IdentityUserLogin<string>, RoleClaim, IdentityUserToken<string>>
{
    public AhanoDBContext()
    {
    }
    public AhanoDBContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        //with this function init all mapping which available in this function(for Identity)
        builder.AddCustomIdentityMappings();
        //with this function init all mapping which available in this function(for Application->Ahano)
        builder.AddCustomAhanoMappings();
        //Take Now DateTime from Server and get value automatically
        builder.Entity<Product>().Property(b => b.PublishDateTime).HasDefaultValueSql("CONVERT(datetime,GetDate())");
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories { set; get; }
    public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { set; get; }
    public virtual DbSet<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ProductsImage> ProductsImages { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Newsletter> Newsletters { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ProductTag> ProductTags { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Has @Pezhvak said: " I even used the parameterless constructor, but it gave another error.".

Comment: An error occurred:
No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

Comment: The missing parameterless constructor was my problem when using Add-Migration.

Answer (score 2):

I came across  the same problem while working with a .NET 7 app. After trying many solutions and failing I found the appropriate solution for this issue that is to move this line `var app = builder.Build();`  below AddDbContext configuration in Program.cs file.

Updated Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AhanoDBContext>(options =>
{
//The name of the connection string is taken from appsetting.json under ConnectionStrings
options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseDBConnString"));
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
 app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
 // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, 
 see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
 app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Comment: `var app = builder.Build();` builds the DI container so everything you try to add to the builder after that is effectively ignored.

Answer (score 0):

My project is also built on Clean Architecture(.NET v7).
I've used "From a design-time factory" trick to have it working.
It needs to implement IDesignTimeDbContextFactory interface.

Taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli